# No attribute for a class in Python

Tags: python, attributes

I just started learning OOPS in python and when I try to run the following code, I get the Attribute error "Area instance has no attribute 'GetLength'"

and also please tell me how to take input from user in the main program but calculation happens in class Area, like take length and width input from user and not set in the program itself.

I hope I made myself clear enough.

```
class Area:
    def __init__ (self , w , l):
        self.width = w
        self.length = l
    def rectangle_area (self):
        return self.width * self.length

    def GetLength (self , len):
        self.length = len

    def GetWidth (self , w):
        self.width = w

    def PrintLength (self):
        return self.length

RecArea = Area(5 , 5)
RecArea.GetLength(10)
print (RecArea.rectangle_area())
input()
```

Comment: Ran your code, no errors... Are you sure you are showing the right source code to the error you are getting ?

Comment: To answer your second question, maybe read into some basic Python tutorial on how to take input in and pass it to a function/class... It's a simple thing and should have been covered before classes, imo...

Comment: @Uriel Eli Probably because the objects gets the length from the context? @ Khayyam Such a method is mostly called setLength, since the context code sets the lenght of the object. And if you're just starting out, it's also a habit to let objects and functions start with lowercase and classes with uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

You mixed tabs and spaces. `GetLength` is actually defined nested inside another method, so `Area` objects don't actually have a `GetLength` method.

Don't mix tabs and spaces. Turn on "show whitespace" in your editor to make these problems more visible, and get a better editor if your editor doesn't support that. Running Python with the `-tt` flag can help catch a bunch of these errors.

---

Aside from the outright error, these `GetLength` and `GetWidth` methods make no sense. They're not getters; they're setters. Also, they break standard Python capitalization conventions, and you don't really need getters or setters for these attributes.